# AWS Lambda layer module has no attributes

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, teradata

I'm trying to import a python module called `teradatasqlalchemy` in an AWS lambda function but when I do this it has no attributes.

I constructed the lambda layer in the usual way.  I made a target directory called `python` and added the module using this command: `pip install --upgrade teradatasqlalchemy -t python`.  Then I zip it up like this  `zip -r sqlalchemy_layer.zip python` and upload to AWS.

If I inspect the directory it looks like everything that's supposed to be there is there.

[image: lambda layer]

Indeed, I can run my lambda like so and it works:

```
import json
import sys, os
from os.path import isfile, join
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import pandas as pd
import time
import json
import pickle

from sqlalchemy import (
    MetaData, Table, ForeignKey, Column, Integer, 
    select, and_, or_, func, cast
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import label
from sqlalchemy.types import BIGINT, VARCHAR, Interval
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import null
import teradatasqlalchemy


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(str(dir(teradatasqlalchemy)))
    }
```

The response is:

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']\""
}
```

Already this looks wrong because this module should have these attributes (from my local env):

```
>>> dir(teradatasqlalchemy)
['BIGINT', 'BLOB', 'BYTE', 'BYTEINT', 'CHAR', 'CLOB', 'DATE', 'DECIMAL', 'FLOAT', 'INTEGER', 'INTERVAL_DAY', 'INTERVAL_DAY_TO_HOUR', 'INTERVAL_DAY_TO_MINUTE', 'INTERVAL_DAY_TO_SECOND', 'INTERVAL_HOUR', 'INTERVAL_HOUR_TO_MINUTE', 'INTERVAL_HOUR_TO_SECOND', 'INTERVAL_MINUTE', 'INTERVAL_MINUTE_TO_SECOND', 'INTERVAL_MONTH', 'INTERVAL_SECOND', 'INTERVAL_YEAR', 'INTERVAL_YEAR_TO_MONTH', 'NUMBER', 'PERIOD_DATE', 'PERIOD_TIME', 'PERIOD_TIMESTAMP', 'SMALLINT', 'TIME', 'TIMESTAMP', 'VARBYTE', 'VARCHAR', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'teradatasql', 'types', 'vernumber']
```

If I change `import teradatasqlalchemy` to `from teradatasqlalchemy import INTERVAL_SECOND` above it throws this error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'INTERVAL_SECOND' from 'teradatasqlalchemy' (unknown location)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

I double checked the version numbers for the local and remote modules and they're both 16.20.0.7.

Any suggestions on how to resolve the empty attribute issue would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.  Just `pip install -t` the modules inside a docker container where the os is amazonLinux.  You can use a mounted volume folder to get the zipfiles back to the host os.

This will make the modules compatible with the lambda environment runtime and when the modules are loaded in lambda they will have the proper attributes.